# Reference to page-range: can LaTeX convert "3-4" to p. 4f or "3-5" to p. 3ff ?

Tags: cross-referencing

The `varioref` package can also cite page ranges by defining a reference to 2 different labels with `\vpagerefrange`.
I did not find information about an option which allows to typeset

- "5-6" as "5f"
- and every range spanning more than 2 pages to "5ff"

Is there a package or an option which allows to do that automatically?

Comment: Take a look at the latest development version of `cleveref`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `varioref` package provides `\vrefpagenum{<macro>}{<ref>}` which stores the page number of the given reference in the macro so that users can define their own vario-style macros. There is an example on page 2f ;-) of the manual.

Here an example implementation. The tests could be optimized a little more.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\vrefff}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \vrefpagenum\@tempa{#1}%
    \vrefpagenum\@tempb{#2}%
    \if ?\@tempa\else
    \if ?\@tempb\else
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
        \@tempa%
    \else
        \ifnum\@tempa>\@tempb\relax
            \let\@tempc\@tempb
            \let\@tempb\@tempa
            \let\@tempa\@tempc
        \fi
        \ifnum\@tempb=\numexpr\@tempa+1\relax\relax
            \@tempa f%
        \else
            \@tempa ff%
        \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

i-vi: \vrefff{i}{vi}

i-ii: \vrefff{i}{ii}

ii-iii: \vrefff{ii}{iii}

iii-ii: \vrefff{iii}{ii}

i-i: \vrefff{i}{i}

iii-vi: \vrefff{iii}{vi}

\section{}\label{i}\newpage
\section{}\label{ii}\newpage
\section{}\label{iii}\newpage
\section{}\label{iv}\newpage
\section{}\label{v}\newpage
\section{}\label{vi}\newpage

\end{document}
```

#### Results in:

```
i-vi: 1ff
i-ii: 1f
ii-iii: 2f
iii-ii: 2f
i-i: 1
iii-vi: 3ff
```