# Shortened page-ranges from \pageref

Tags: numbering, cross-referencing, formatting

In some typographic conventions page-ranges are shortened to save space, e.g. writing 
"1234-35" 
or even 
"1234-5"
instead of 
"1234-1235". I would like to have a `\pageref{foo}--\pageref{bar}` automatically shortened to either of these formats.

I gather from the answer to
[Reference to page-range: can LaTeX convert "3-4" to p. 4f or "3-5" to p. 3ff ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15879/reference-to-page-range-can-latex-convert-3-4-to-p-4f-or-3-5-to-p-3ff) that `varioref` should be able to do this, but adapting Martin Scharrer's customisation to my problem is frankly over my head.

How could I do this?

Or have I overlooked another package, that does this out of the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there weren't any takers, I experimented my way to the following, using Martin Scharrer's    example mentioned above. Improvements are very welcome!

Commenting out the first conditional results in the "1234-35"-format.

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{varioref}


\makeatletter


\newcommand*{\vrefabbr}[2]{%
\begingroup
    \vrefpagenum\@tempa{#1}%
    \vrefpagenum\@tempb{#2}%
    \if ?\@tempa\else
    \if ?\@tempb\else
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
        \@tempa%
    \else
        \ifnum\@tempa>\@tempb\relax
            \let\@tempc\@tempb
            \let\@tempb\@tempa
            \let\@tempa\@tempc
        \fi
        \ifnum\numexpr(\@tempa-5)/10= \numexpr(\@tempb-5)/10\relax
            \@tempa --\the\numexpr\@tempb-(\@tempb-5)/10*10\relax
        \else
            \ifnum\numexpr(\@tempa-50)/100= \numexpr(\@tempb-50)/100\relax
                \@tempa --\the\numexpr\@tempb-(\@tempb-50)/100*100\relax
            \else
                \ifnum\numexpr(\@tempa-500)/1000= \numexpr(\@tempb-500)/1000\relax
                    \@tempa --\the\numexpr\@tempb-(\@tempb-500)/1000*1000\relax
                \else
                    \@tempa --\@tempb%
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


ix--x: \vrefabbr{ix}{x}

ix--xiv: \vrefabbr{ix}{xiv}

xi--xiv: \vrefabbr{xi}{xiv}

xi--xv: \vrefabbr{xi}{xv}

xi--xvi: \vrefabbr{xi}{xvi}

xi--xii: \vrefabbr{xi}{xii}

xii--xiii: \vrefabbr{xii}{xiii}

xiii--xii: \vrefabbr{xiii}{xii}

xi--xi: \vrefabbr{xi}{xi}

xiii--xvi: \vrefabbr{xiii}{xvi}

xiii--xx: \vrefabbr{xiii}{xx}

xx--xxi: \vrefabbr{xx}{xxi}

xx--xxii: \vrefabbr{xx}{xxii}

xi--xxi: \vrefabbr{xi}{xxi}

xi--xx: \vrefabbr{xi}{xx}

cxix--cxvi: \vrefabbr{cxix}{cxvi}

cxix--cxii: \vrefabbr{cxix}{cxxii}

cxii--cxiii: \vrefabbr{cxii}{cxiii}

cxiii--cxii: \vrefabbr{cxiii}{cxxii}

cxi--cxi: \vrefabbr{cxi}{cxi}

cxiii--cxvi: \vrefabbr{cxiii}{cxvi}

cxiii--cxx: \vrefabbr{cxiii}{cxx}

cxx--cxxi: \vrefabbr{cxx}{cxxi}

cxx--cxxii: \vrefabbr{cxx}{cxxii}

cxi--cxxi: \vrefabbr{cxi}{cxxi}

cxi--cxx: \vrefabbr{cxi}{cxx}

cxi--cxxii: \vrefabbr{cxi}{cxxii}

mcxi--mcxvi: \vrefabbr{mcxi}{mcxvi}

mcxi--mcxii: \vrefabbr{mcxi}{mcxii}

mcxii--mcxiii: \vrefabbr{mcxii}{mcxiii}

mcxiii--mcxii: \vrefabbr{mcxiii}{mcxii}

mcxi--mcxi: \vrefabbr{mcxi}{mcxi}

mcxiii--mcxvi: \vrefabbr{mcxiii}{mcxvi}

mcxiii--mcxx: \vrefabbr{mcxiii}{mcxx}

mcxx--mcxxi: \vrefabbr{mcxx}{mcxxi}

mcxx--mcxxii: \vrefabbr{mcxx}{mcxxii}

mcxi--mcxxi: \vrefabbr{mcxi}{mcxxi}

mcxi--mcxx: \vrefabbr{mcxi}{mcxx}

mcxi--mcxxii: \vrefabbr{mcxi}{mcxxii}

cxi--mcxxii: \vrefabbr{cxi}{mcxxii}

cxi--mcxxii: \vrefabbr{cxi}{mcxxii}

xi--mcxxii: \vrefabbr{xi}{mcxxii}

ix--mcxxii: \vrefabbr{ix}{mcxxii}

mccxxxiv--mccxxxv \vrefabbr{mccxxxiv}{mccxxxv}


\setcounter{page}{9}
\section{}\label{ix}\newpage
\section{}\label{x}\newpage
\section{}\label{xi}\newpage
\section{}\label{xii}\newpage
\section{}\label{xiii}\newpage
\section{}\label{xiv}\newpage
\section{}\label{xv}\newpage
\section{}\label{xvi}\newpage
\section{}\label{xvii}\newpage
\section{}\label{xviii}\newpage
\section{}\label{xix}\newpage
\section{}\label{xx}\newpage
\section{}\label{xxi}\newpage
\section{}\label{xxii}\newpage

\setcounter{page}{111}
\section{}\label{cxi}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxii}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxiii}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxiv}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxv}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxvi}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxvii}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxviii}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxix}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxx}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxxi}\newpage
\section{}\label{cxxii}\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1111}
\section{}\label{mcxi}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxii}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxiii}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxiv}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxv}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxvi}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxvii}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxviii}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxix}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxx}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxxi}\newpage
\section{}\label{mcxxii}\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1234}
\section{}\label{mccxxxiv}\newpage
\section{}\label{mccxxxv}\newpage




\end{document}
```