# Cleveref: abbreviation for following page(s) (f./ff.)

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I want `cleveref` to display references to page ranges of one or two pages as "5f." or "5ff." instead of "5–6" or "5–7" respectively.

According to Martin Schröder's comment in [Reference to page-range: can LaTeX convert "3-4" to p. 4f or "3-5" to p. 3ff ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15879/reference-to-page-range-can-latex-convert-3-4-to-p-4f-or-3-5-to-p-3ff) this should be doable, unfortunately, I couldn't find any hints on how to achieve this.

Comment: This seems like a feature request -- albeit an excellent feature request. Feature requests are generally discouraged on this site. Have you contacted Toby Cubitt, the author of the `cleveref` package, about this?

Comment: No, I haven't contacted Toby Cubitt. Martin Schröder's comment suggested that this was already doable though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with the `\cpagerangelabelformat{type}{format}` macro.

The format can use `#1` to `#6` argument values, `#1` and `#2` are the real page counter values as extracted from the `.aux` file.

This example is not yet perfect, but it shows the correct value for one page or a page difference more than 1 and exactly one.

It does **not** treat the case the page labels occuring in wrong order!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{cleveref}


\crefrangelabelformat{page}{%
  \ifnum #2 = #1 % same page
  #1% 
  \else
  \ifnum #2 > \numexpr #1+1\relax % Difference > 1
  #1ff.\@%
  \else
  #1f.\@%    Difference = 1
  \fi
  \fi
}



\begin{document}

In \cpagerefrange{sec:one}{sec:one} we see

In \cpagerefrange{sec:one}{sec:another} we see

In \cpagerefrange{sec:one}{sec:yetanother} we have

Wrong usage (reversed labels!): in \cpagerefrange{sec:yetanother}{sec:one}


\section{A section} \label{sec:one}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Another section} \label{sec:another}

\blindtext[10]

\section{Yet another section} \label{sec:yetanother}

\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing a few end-of-line `%` :) (three to be precise)

Comment: @clemens: My first version always lack them ;-) Sometimes the last one too ;-)

Comment: You were also missing `\relax` at the end of the `\numexpr`. Not strictly needed, but clearer. Also `\@` after the periods was missing.

Comment: @egreg: Why `\@`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No sentence ending period.

Comment: Let's hope that the `\cpagerefrange` macro only gets used if there's more than one page involved -- "In pages 1" is rather hard on the eyes...

Comment: @egreg - It's not necessarily true that the `.` in `f.` or `ff.` cannot not occur at the end a sentence. It may therefore be better to omit the `\@` directives and inform the OP that he/she needs to remember to insert `\ ` (space) after `\cpagerefrange{sec:one}{sec:yetanother}` if the directive does *not* occur at end of a sentence.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mention that I wanted `p. 4–7` if it was more than two consecutive pages, but starting from your solution I could expand it.

Comment: @Mico: Yes, I was in a hurry. I will improve later on

Comment: @Simifilm: No, that was not in your question -- p.4-7 is totally different from 1ff etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Adapting your solution proved actually to be quite easy.